# Adding Style property to UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-3.5

I am having difficulties in adding Style property to a UserControl. There is a parser exception when I try to view the consumer page.

```
private Style _headerStyle = new Style();
public Style HeaderStyle
{
    get { return _headerStyle ; }
    set
    {
        _headerStyle .CopyFrom(value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Style="border: 1px solid blue;"
```

Error:

```
Cannot create an object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Style' from its string representation ...
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: I don't understand why it is voted down. I simply want to know the answer. There is nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

A `Style` instance is not a string and vice-versa. [`Style.CopyFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.copyfrom%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) expects a `Style` as argument and you're passing a `String`. That's the reason why it cannot be copied to the new style object.

If you want to give your UserControl a border programmatically:

```
myControl.HeaderStyle.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
myControl.HeaderStyle.BorderWidth = new Unit(1);
myControl.HeaderStyle.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but what I am looking for is how to expose the Style property to the consumer of the UserControl. I am trying to mimic the System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebControl.Style property.

Answer (score 0):

You'r trying to create an ASP.NET [Style](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.style.aspx) but declaring a CSS Style, that's the problem. If you want to apply an ASP.NET style you need to call the ApplyStyle method instead:

```
control.ApplyStyle(styleName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply as well. In fact, I am looking for the way that allows me to expose the Style property.